# Java programming deadlock

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

Problem: My question is regarding the synchronise keyword and deadlocks. If i was to have a java program with only a single synchronised method it cannot possibly  deadlock right?

Explanation of my Answer: Well, i am coming to the conclusion that this statement is false as the only scenario i can think of is that what about if the synchronised method calls for another method which locks and waits for the synchronised method to release its lock

However on the other hand, i have said that the program contains a single synchronised method.Therefore there are not other method so it cannot possibly deadlock

Comment: A deadlock can only occur when these [four conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Individually_necessary_and_jointly_sufficient_conditions_for_deadlock) are met. If any of them is not met, there's no deadlock. So you can check for yourself using these conditions

Comment: Well, the synchronise keyword enforces mutual exclusion therefore it cannot lead to deadlock however incorrect use of locks can lead to deadlock i.e by calling the single synchronised method  in the program again recursively. So the statement is false no? or am i confusing myself –

Comment: One way to disprove the proposition that deadlock is impossible is to write an application with one `synchronized` method that can deadlock.  Hints:  1) consider a recursive method, 2) you need two locks (i.e. two objects) and two threads to get a deadlock.

Comment: @StephenC yes i guess my statement "f i was to have a java program with only a single synchronised method it cannot possibly deadlock right" is false as a recursive method in the synchronised method can cause a deadlock

Answer (score 2):

> If i was to have a java program with only a single `synchronized` method it cannot possibly deadlock right?

Incorrect.  Here is a counter example.

```
 public class Demo {

     public synchronized void op(Demo other) {
         try {
             Thread.sleep(2000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
             // ignore
         }
         if (other != null) {
             other.op(null);
         } else {
             System.out.println("I have both locks!");
         }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Demo d1 = new Demo();
         Demo d2 = new Demo();
         new Thread(() -> d1.op(d2)).start();
         new Thread(() -> d2.op(d1)).start();
     }
 }
```

It is not the number of methods that matter.  It is the number of locks and the number of threads.  For instance methods that are `synchronized`, the lock is the instance that you are calling the method on.

So the above example has two threads and two locks ... and I have arranged that the two threads attempt to acquire both locks, but in a different order.  (With a `sleep` call to make sure that the two threads overlap in time.)